# JBoss 4.2.3 integration with ActiveMQ 5.15.0

Tags: java, jboss, activemq-classic

I have a JBoss 4.2.3 application server that needs to integrate with ActiveMQ (actually AWS MQ which wraps around ActiveMQ 5.15.0). It is a pretty ancient version of JBoss and I was able to make my application work with Java 8, which is what the latest ActiveMQ needs (I believe it is Java 7+).

The need is to replace the embedded JBossMQ and use a more recent and effective message broker (JBossMQ has a lot of issues). I configured that activemq-ra.rar and placed it in jboss/server/default/deploy/jms directory.

However, on startup, an "empty" JBoss (no custom WAR or EAR applications), I'm getting:

```
--- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionFactory,name=JmsXA
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: couldn't get 
oldRarDeployment! 
jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='activemq.rar'; - nested 
throwable: (org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: 
ConnectionDefinition 
'org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory' not found 
in rar 'activemq.rar')
  I Depend On:
    jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='activemq.rar'
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionPool,name=JmsXA

--- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionFactory,name=JmsXA
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: couldn't get         
oldRarDeployment! 
jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='activemq.rar'; - nested 
throwable: (org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: 
ConnectionDefinition 
'org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory' not found 
in rar 'activemq.rar')
  I Depend On: 
    jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='activemq.rar'
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionPool,name=JmsXA
```

I extracted the contents of the RAR file and I do see *activemq-ra-5.15.0.jar*, which after extracting does contain the class org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You didn't mention it so I figure it was worth asking if you'd been through the ActiveMQ tutorial on this subject - http://activemq.apache.org/jboss-integration.html.

Comment: yes, though I'm using more up to date versions of ActiveMQ and JBoss and not an embedded container - a standalone ActiveMQ instance on a different server.

Answer (score 0):

My ActiveMQ 5.11 rar file contains:

```
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_85
```

If your JCA rar file has a Java 7 dependency, you will not be able to use it on JBoss 4.2.3

Comment: I'm able to run JBoss using Java 8 successfully, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hi [Jonathan T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5775612/jonathan-t):
I know that this post is 3 years old, but I am unfortunatly struggling a problem that you may have resolved.
Did you succeed to use a **standalone ActiveMQ** as the/a **JMS-Broker** in your **jBoss-4.2.3**?
If so could you please tell how you achieved that?